# Column names with @MappedSuperclass and @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm experiencing some problems with the proper column names when using inheritance in JPA. We have a bunch of classes in an HR system, many of which share a business group and employee number. The database could be set up better, but let's assume for the moment that I have no control over it. All tables that somehow refer to an employee have the `business_group_id` and `employee_number` fields. There is also a `com_business_group` table.

In an attempt to create some order in the chaos of entities and repositories, I've created these classes:

`BusinessGroup.java`:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "from")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "com_business_groups")
public class BusinessGroup implements net.megabyte.hr.model.domain.BusinessGroup {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 738407784303616207L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "business_group_id", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String id;

    // more fields, none of them particularly relevant
}
```

`AbstractHasBusinessGroup.java`:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class AbstractHasBusinessGroup implements HasBusinessGroup {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_group_id", referencedColumnName = "business_group_id")
    private BusinessGroup businessGroup;

    @Transient
    public String getBusinessGroupId() {
        return businessGroup.getId();
    }
}
```

`HasBusinessGroup.java`:

```
public interface HasBusinessGroup {

    BusinessGroup getBusinessGroup();
}
```

`AbstractHasEmployee.java`:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractHasEmployee extends AbstractHasBusinessGroup implements HasEmployee {

    @Embedded
    protected EmployeeId employeeId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "business_group_jd", referencedColumnName = "business_group_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "employee_number", referencedColumnName = "employee_number")
    })
    private Employee employee;

    @Transient
    public String getBusinessGroupId() {
        return employeeId.getBusinessGroupId();
    }

    @Transient
    public String getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeId.getEmployeeNumber();
    }
}
```

`HasEmployee.java`:

```
public interface HasEmployee {

    EmployeeId getEmployeeId();

    Employee getEmployee();
}
```

`EmployeeId.java`:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "from")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3733372990919290775L;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "business_group_id", referencedColumnName = "business_group_id")
    private BusinessGroup businessGroup;

    @Column(name = "employee_number", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String employeeNumber;

    @Transient
    public String getBusinessGroupId() {
        return businessGroup.getId();
    }
}
```

`Employee.java`:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "from")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "mpy_employees")
public class Employee implements HasId<EmployeeId>, Comparable<Employee> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -881308634763263382L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;

    // more employee-related stuff such as name, date of birth, etc
}
```

So far, so good. The trouble starts when I have the following class, and try to create a Spring application context for unit test:

`HierarchyEmployee.java`:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "from")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
//@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "web_approval_struct",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"employee_number", "businessGroup", "hierarchy_name"})
)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class HierarchyEmployee extends AbstractHasEmployee implements HasLongId, HasEmployee {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6322364890608829221L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "superior")
    private List<HierarchyEmployee> subEmployees = new ArrayList<>();

    // some more properties relating to the structure
}
```

I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: business_group_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(mpy_employees) and its related supertables and secondary tables

When turning on debug logging, I can see that the column `businessGroup` is created:

> [test] DEBUG [main] Ejb3Column.bind(213) | Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(web_approval_struct), mappingColumn=businessGroup, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}

The `employee_number` and `hierarchy_name` columns are created without a problem. So how do I tell JPA/Hibernate that I would really like to have the `business_group_id` column instead?

Comment: I ought to mention that I found some extraneous bindings in the properties I labelled "irrelevant". But it's still giving problems. I'll report my findings here once I figure it out – unless somebody else provided the solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: the problem was that some classes still had their own references to `BusinessGroup` or `Employee`, in addition to inheriting them from the abstract base classes. Hibernate's error messages didn't help in this regard.

I also moved the abstract base classes to a package where they wouldn't be included in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation, just to be on the safe side.